# Отношение один ко многим и один к одному

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Помогите понять. Есть некоторая модель базы, с ней вопросов нету, но то как я расставляю отношения сущности - говорят не верно. Объясните почему. 
Есть животные, есть корма, есть миски. Модель базы: у каждого животного свой набор мисок, в каждой миске лежит только определенный вид корма. Двух мисок у одного животного с одним кормом быть не может.

Как я строю:

*животное* **1<>----n** *миска* **n----<>1** *корм*

моя логика в том что у каждого животного может быть множество мисок, у каждой миски только определенное животное. У каждой миски строго определенный корм. У корма может быть множество мисок.

Мне же говорят что в модели связь миска - корм должна быть 1 к 1, т.е. вот так:

*животное*  **1<>----n**  *миска*  **1----<>1**   *корм*

Почему 1 к 1?

Comment: так вы сами же написали `в каждой миске лежит только определенный вид корма.` от сюда и вытекает это отношение

Comment: так и получается что около корма от миски стоит 1. У каждого животного свой набор мисок. У другого животного может оказаться миска с таким же кормом потому у миски n.

Comment: Да, но один и тот же корм может быть в разных мисках. ограничение только на корм-миска для одного конкретного животного. и такая уникальность если и поддерживается, то только триггерами. обычными отношениями она не описывается. Судя по всему человек утверждающий, что нужна 1-1 как раз за счет этого хочет обеспечить уникальность корма для животного. Но он не прав. Я бы  с ним поспорил.

Comment: Ели уж очень хочется описать эту уникальность отношениями, то я вижу один выход: нам нужна еще одна странная сущность кормо-животное. Т.е. таблица с ID-животного и ID-корма это связь многие ко многим. Но в таблице поддерживается уникальность этой связи. Причем у этой связи есть собственный ID и вот он отношением 1-1 связан с миской. Реальную базу так никто (надеюсь) проектировать не будет

Comment: @Mike Вот я и спорю) правда опыта в базах не много и думаю может чего я не понимаю, но почитал, в итоге остался при своем мнении.

Comment: Если ограничиться одним животным, то там действительно 1..1, но в общем случае там 1..N, я считаю, что вы правы.